# How to find the resultant vector in a word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, word-problem

If the wind blows at 20 mph due West and an airplane heads South at 400 mph, what is the resultant speed and direction of the plane?

Comment: Have you learned how to add vectors?

Comment: Sofar I only know how to add them just by adding up the corresponding numbers. I am confused how to do it graphically (the head-tail way)

Comment: Okay.  I recommend reading a source online.  There are a whole bunch of them, but [this one](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/vectors/U3L1b.cfm#head) seems like it has what you're looking for under the section labeled "The Pythagorean Theorem."

Comment: Thank you, that helped alot. So is the plane going 400.5 mph at 87 degrees south of West?

Comment: Yes.  I'm glad that link was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the velocity of the plane relative to the earth is $$\left(\begin{matrix}-20\\-400\end{matrix}\right)$$

So you can calculate the speed and bearing from this?

Comment: So do you just use the pythagorean theorem with leg sides 20 and 400 to get the hypotenuse 400.5 as the speed? and the direction is southwest?

Comment: Not southwest exactly: you need to use trigonometry